Reverse Proxy for Nextjs App in WHM and Nginx Restart to default config
I'm just trying to setup a reverse proxy for my nextjs app in whm. I was trying to map port 3000 to 443 by editing the /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf and /etc/nginx/conf.d/ea-nginx.conf file. but after few days these files return to its predefined initial values like proxy_pass port and ssl key and cert paths(it seems to be a cron job). I just tried couple of ways like removing ea-nginx from scripts path but no luck. would you please help me with that?
Many thanks
